# Bind a property to a custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I have a custom control library that I am using and I have added a property called `DataCodeField` that acts nearly the same as `DataTextField` for a control that inherits from `ComboBox`.

```
    DummyData data1 = new DummyData(12, "Jon", 1);
    DummyData data2 = new DummyData(15, "Bill", 2);
    DummyData data3 = new DummyData(23, "Ted", 1);

    var people = new List<DummyData>{data1, data2, data3};

    ddlTest.DataSource = people;
    ddlTest.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddlTest.DataCodeField = "Age";
    ddlTest.DataValueField = "Id";
    ddlTest.DataBind();

    var id = ddlTest.SelectedValue;
    var index = ddlTest.SelectedIndex;
    var name = ddlTest.SelectedItem;
    var age = ??
```

I need to find the persons age when I bound it to the new `DataCodeField`. I know I have to override the `OnDataBinding` event to do this but I can't seem to find where to start. Any help would be appreciated. My end goal is to access the age like this after the combobox has been databound.

Alternatively, is there a way to access the bound datasource and then access the age from that object based on the selectedIndex?

Comment: Not really sure if this helps, but what is the type of the control at the time you are trying to retrieve the values from `ddlTest` control? If it's not the type you originally defined, maybe you want to cast it into your type.

Comment: I am not an expert it but when you bind data to DDL, doesn't it has to be in pair (name, value), otherwise it will give you error. Your code seems fine except what I pointed above.

Comment: It is of the right type. This has to do with retrieving the object from the bound datasource.

Comment: @JonathanO Another thing that I'm thinking... Did you implement the same customization to the `ListItem` control? Once you bind the `DropDownList` I believe the items will be of the type `ListItem` and they might not have that extra property... anyway.. just a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save the datasource in viewstate you can access the selected age using;

```
var age = People[ddlTest.SelectedIndex].Age;
```

Comment: This is possible for sure but I do not want to bloat the viewstate with large objects.

Comment: Just put the Age in its own list in ViewState than: `var age = Ages[ddlTest.SelectedIndex];`